# Move scrollbar div to specific part of page

Tags: html, css, scrollview, scrollbar

I'm making a page and I have some problems moving my scrollbar-div across the page, when in the right top corner everything works perfectly but when I try to move it to the center of the page with margin-left; and margin-top; the scrollfunction dose not work anymore! Could this have anything to do with the other elements on my page? Any tips or similar experiences?

Appreciate any help!

This code works, if I ad margin-top: 100px; it stops working!
Html:

```
<div class="scrollbox" id="style">
    <div class="overflow"></div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.scrollbox {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 700px;
    background: #ccc;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.overflow {
    min-height: 700px;
}

#style::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code what you have done so far.

Comment: I'm sorry, new at this, i will add it!

Comment: Took a while to figure out how to add the code without it looking bad, haha but I think it is readable now :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, after posting the question I figured out the answer, or at least one answer, if 
   `position: absolute;` is added in the `scrollbox{}` element in the css code, it is possible to move the scrollbox without losing the scroll-function.